# Can a chord determine two fundamental circuits in a graph

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-traversal

I was studying fundamental circuits,fundamental cutsets related theorems,then I came across a question in my mind:
Is it possible that a chord with respect to a given spanning tree  in a graph determine two fundamental circuit?

Comment: This might be more suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okhay thanks a lot... actually  I did not know about this.